# Questions about qt5 dynamic link library

Tags: c++, qt

I'm more curious if it's possible to apply qt's dynamic link library (dll) to a normal cpp program.

For example, I wrote an interface on qt and then generated a dynamic link library, the function of this interface is just to display the input characters, and then use cpp to call this dynamic link library, and input the characters output from the cpp to qt's dynamic link library through the interface to finally display them through the interface.

Comment: There is no fundamental law of physics preventing you from compiling Qt code into a library nor loading said library like any other. As long as there is an instance of `QApplication` created somewhere (could be done by your library) any Qt GUI code should just work.

Answer (score 0):

for what i know you just need to create a main.cpp file and use the funtion created with the qt library. Just remeber to tell your compiler where to find the headers and the dll's.